# Unity3d character move with arrows keys from point to point

Tags: unity-game-engine, unityscript

I have a waypoints script that I apply to an object. For example, on a character that goes from point to point and stops for a certain time and then continues to walk. How can I modify the code if I wanted to control the character with the arrow keys on the keyboard, but still have them walk from point to point, staying on the route.

```
@script ExecuteInEditMode()

var PathFolder : GameObject;
@Range (1.0, 18.0) 
var speed : float = 3.0;
var closedLoop : boolean;
var usePingpong : boolean;
var showPaths : boolean = true;
@Range (10, 100) 
var SlerpSegments : int = 20;
var useSlerp : boolean;
@Range (.01, .4) 
var slerpPoint: float = .1; // amount before turning
//enum SlerpColor { Black=0,White=1,Grey=2,Blue=3,Cyan=4,Green=5,Magenta=6,Red=7,Yellow=8}
//var slerpColor = SlerpColor.Cyan;
//var colorArray = Array();
//var scolor;

private var numpoints : int=0;
private var curindex : int ;  // current index
private var once : int = 0;
private var purpleArray = Array() ;
private var ppoint : float = 1.0 ;  // purple point
private var ptimes : int = 0 ;  // purple

private var waypoints = Array();
private var target : Vector3;
private var dir: Vector3; // direction
private var disttotarget: float;  //distance to target
private var distofline: float;  //distance of current line 
private var distnormal: float;  //distance normalized 
private var rot: Quaternion; // rotation 
private var turnam: float; // rotation 
var stop : boolean;
var timer : float ; 

private var cislo : float = 4.0 ;  // purple point
 function Start(){



 }
function Update(){


        if (!Application.isPlaying) {
        RebuildWaypointList (); DrawWaypoints (); return;
    }
    if(showPaths) DrawWaypoints (); // remark this out later to speed up the program
    if(once==0) RebuildWaypointList ();
        MoveForward();
    turnam=0.01;  // for no slerping = almost at zero
    if (useSlerp)turnam=slerpPoint; 
    if (distnormal<turnam)NextWayPoint();

}


//============= subroutines =============

function MoveForward(){



        FindDistance(); dir= target - transform.position;
    //==========================
    if(useSlerp){
        var rot: Quaternion = Quaternion.LookRotation(dir);
    transform.rotation = Quaternion.Slerp(transform.rotation, rot, speed * Time.deltaTime);
    } else {
        transform.LookAt(target);  // no Slerping
    }
    // move in the current forward direction at specified speed:
    // to keep it grounded , use Rigidbody and check "Use Gravity".
    //Debug.Log(curindex);
if(stop){
     timer -= Time.deltaTime;
     transform.Translate(Vector3.zero);

     if(timer <= 0){
        timer = 0.0;

        stop=false;                      // kocka může zase jít
        transform.Translate(Vector3(0, 0, speed * Time.deltaTime));   

    }else{            
 // timer -= Time.deltaTime;
  transform.Translate(Vector3.zero);
}                  

}else{
transform.Translate(Vector3(0, 0, speed * Time.deltaTime)); 
}
}
function NextWayPoint(){



switch(curindex){


case 4:  stop=true;          //stop in point 3

               timer=5;              //5s

               break;
default: stop=false;       //go

                }

    if((curindex+1) < numpoints){   // normal going forward
        curindex+=1;
    }else{
        curindex=0; 
    }
    // ========= if ping pong then reverse  =========
    if(usePingpong && curindex==0){  // then at the end 

            // swap allthe Vector3 info in waypoints()
        var n=numpoints-1; var nn=(numpoints)/2;
        for(var a : int = 0; a <nn; a++){
            var tempVector=waypoints[a];
            waypoints[a] = waypoints[n-a]; 
            waypoints[n-a] = tempVector; 
        }
        curindex=0;     target=waypoints[curindex]; return;
    }
    // ========= if no loop then jump to beginning =========
    if(!closedLoop && curindex==0){
        curindex=1; target=waypoints[1];  
            // go to first waypoint and exit subroutine
        transform.position=waypoints[0]; 
        transform.LookAt(target); 
        return;
    }
    target=waypoints[curindex];   // else update target
}


function FindDistance(){
    var tempindex = curindex;
    if((tempindex-1) >-0.5){
        tempindex-=1;
    }else{
        tempindex=numpoints-1; 
    }
    distofline = Vector3.Distance(target,waypoints[tempindex]);
    disttotarget= Vector3.Distance(target,transform.position);
    distnormal= disttotarget/distofline;  // make a percentage  0.0 to 1.0
}


// =========================================
function RebuildWaypointList () {
    var allpoints = PathFolder.GetComponentsInChildren(Transform);
    for(var i : int = 1; i < allpoints.Length; i++){
        waypoints[i-1] = (allpoints[i].position); 
    }
    numpoints=allpoints.Length-1;
    once=1;   // flag to do this coroutine only once
    target=waypoints[curindex];  // starts at 0
}


// =========================================
function DrawWaypoints () {
    //if (Application.isPlaying)  return;
    for ( i=0; i < numpoints; i++){
        if (i<numpoints-1){  // open path  -1
            if (Physics.Linecast(waypoints[i],waypoints[i+1])) {  // true if collider
            Debug.DrawLine (waypoints[i],waypoints[i+1], Color.red);
            }else{
            Debug.DrawLine (waypoints[i],waypoints[i+1], Color.green);
            }
        }
        else if(closedLoop) {  // closed loop
            if (Physics.Linecast(waypoints[i],waypoints[0])) {  // true if collider
            Debug.DrawLine (waypoints[i],waypoints[0], Color.red);
            }else{
            Debug.DrawLine (waypoints[i],waypoints[0], Color.blue);
            }
        }
    }

    if (Application.isPlaying) {  // game is running ... draw purple path
        ppoint -=Time.deltaTime;   // one second?

        if(ppoint<0){
                    //print("ptimes1 =" + ptimes + " : purpArray ="+purpleArray);
            purpleArray.Add(this.transform.position); ptimes +=1;
            if(ptimes>SlerpSegments){
                purpleArray.RemoveAt(0);  // remove the first index
                ptimes -=1; 
            }
            //print("ptimes2 =" + ptimes + " : purpArray ="+purpleArray);
            ppoint=(1/speed)*.75;
        }

        SelectColor();

        if(ptimes<1 || !useSlerp)return;
        for ( i=0; i < ptimes-1; i++){
            //Debug.Log("parray" +i+"=" +purpleArray[i]+ " parray"+(i+1)+"=" + purpleArray[i+1]);
            var a = purpleArray[i]; 
            var b = purpleArray[i+1];
            //Debug.Log(">>" + a + b);
            Debug.DrawLine (a,b, Color.magenta);
        }
    }
}

function SelectColor(){
// I gave up on this after a whole day...... maybe you can get it working.

//var colors : Color[]={Color.black=0,Color.white=1}
//,Color.grey,Color.blue,Color.cyan,Color.green,Color.magenta,Color.red,Color.yellow}
//GUI.color = new Color( 1, 1, 1, 0.5f )

    //GUI.color = colors[1];
    //Black=0,White=1,Grey=2,Blue=3,Cyan=4,
    //Green=5,Magenta=6,Red=7,Yellow=8

    //print("GUIcolor="+GUI.color);

//int indx= Random.Range(0,colors.Length);

//GUIText.material.color = colors[indx];

        //  print("color="+slerpColor);
    //if(slerpColor="Magenta")scolor="magenta";
    //colorArray[0] = Vector4(0,0,0,1);
    //colorArray[1] = Vector4(1,1,1,1);
    //var cVector = colorArray[1];      print ("cv " +cVector);
    //GUI.color = new Color(colorArray[1]);

    //print (colorArray);
    //var color : Color = Color(0.2, 0.3, 0.4, 0.5);
    //print ("v=" + colorArray[1]);
        //GUI.color= colorArray[1];

    /*
    black   Solid black. RGBA is (0, 0, 0, 1).
blue    Solid blue. RGBA is (0, 0, 1, 1).
clear   Completely transparent. RGBA is (0, 0, 0, 0).
cyan    Cyan. RGBA is (0, 1, 1, 1).
gray    Gray. RGBA is (0.5, 0.5, 0.5, 1).
green   Solid green. RGBA is (0, 1, 0, 1).
grey    English spelling for gray. RGBA is the same (0.5, 0.5, 0.5, 1).
magenta Magenta. RGBA is (1, 0, 1, 1).
red Solid red. RGBA is (1, 0, 0, 1).
white   Solid white. RGBA is (1, 1, 1, 1).
yellow  Yellow. RGBA is (1, 0.92, 0.016, 1), but the color is nice to look at!

var colors : Color[] = {Color.red, Color.cyan, Color.yellow }; //etc

    switch (slerpColor)  {
        case 0: GUI.color = Color.black; break;
        case 1: GUI.color = Color.white; break;
        case 2: GUI.color = Color.grey; break;
        case 3: GUI.color = Color.blue; break;
        case 4: GUI.color = Color.cyan; break;
        case 5: GUI.color = Color.green; break;
        case 6: GUI.color = Color.magenta; break;
        case 7: GUI.color = Color.red; break;
        case 8: GUI.color = Color.yellow; break;
    }
                //print("scolor="+scolor);
    //GUI.color = Color.scolor;
    //Black=0,White=1,Grey=2,Blue=3,Cyan=4,
    //Green=5,Magenta=6,Red=7,Yellow=8

    print("GUIcolor="+GUI.color);
        */
}
```

Answer (score 0):

Move

```
if (distnormal<turnam)NextWayPoint();
```

into a KeyDown event handler.